# Scriptural mentions of Sri Ramanandacharya

Tags: ramanand, ramanandi, srisampraday, ramanandacharya, tulsidas

What is the Scriptural mentions of Srimad Jagadguru Ramanandacharya?

Answer (score 1):

> रामानन्दः स्वयं रामः प्रादुर्भूतो महीतले। कलौ लोके मुनिर्जातः
> सर्वजीवदयापरः॥ तप्तकांचनसंकाशो रामानन्दः स्वयं हरि:॥ (वैश्वानर संहिता)
>
> **rāmānandaḥ svayaṃ rāmaḥ prādurbhūtō mahītalē**। kalau lōkē munirjātaḥ
> sarvajīvadayāparaḥ॥ **taptakāṃcanasaṃkāśō rāmānandaḥ svayaṃ hari**:॥
> (**Vaiśvānara Saṃhitā**)
>
> “**Jagadguru Bhagavān Śrī Rāmānanda is the incarnation of the supreme
> personality of Godhead Bhagavān Śrī Rāma himself who appeared on this
> earth in the form of a great Muni (sage) out of his causeless mercy
> and compassion on all Jivas. Bhagavān Ramanand was the Supreme Lord
> Śrī Hari Himself**, having bodily lustre of molten gold in this
> Kaliyuga.”

Answer (score 0):

Anand Bhashyakar Jagadguru Ramanandacharya

[image]

> आचार्या बहवोऽभूवन् प्रवर्तकाः ।
>
> किन्तु देवि कलेरादी पाखण्ड प्रचुरे जने ॥
>
> रामानन्देति भविता विष्णुधर्म प्रवर्तकः ।
>
> यदा यदा हि धर्मोऽयं विष्णोः साकेतवासिनः ॥
>
> कृशतामेति भो देवि तदा सः भगवान् हरिः।
>
> रामानन्द यतिर्भूत्वा तीर्थराजे च पावने ॥
>
> अन्तर्यामी महायोगी अवतीर्य जगन्नाथ ।
>
> धर्मं स्थापयते पुनः देशकालावच्छिन्नो विष्णोधर्मः सुखप्रदः ॥

There were many Acharya-s who were the Promoter (प्रवर्तक) of Sri Ram Mantra, but O Goddess! At the beginning of Kali Yuga, when there will be many hypocrites than the acharya who will be the Promoter of Vaishnavism will be famous by the name of Śrī Ramanand. Whenever this religion of Vishnu who resides in Saket attains its decline, then O Goddess! Lord Hari by becoming a Yati (Great Scholar) named Sri Ramanand, incarnates in the holy Tirtharaj Prayag. The Antaryaami, The Greatest Yogi, The Jagannatha will descend and will re-establish the Vaishnava Religion. The religious principles of Viṣṇu are different from space & time and always bring happiness to Human Kind.

**(Valmiki Samhita Chapter 5 Verse 23-26, Śrī Sesha Math edition, Gujrat )**

> रामानन्द इति ख्यातो लोकोद्धरणकारणः।
>
> आचार्यलक्षणैर्युक्तं वेदवेदान्तपरागम् ॥
>
> श्रीसंप्रदायश्रेष्ठञ्च जनोद्धारपरं सदा ।
>
> विज्ञाय राघवानन्दं लब्ध्वा तस्मात् षडक्षरम् ॥

Sri Ramananda is known as the cause of lifting the world. He is endowed with the characteristics of acharya and is well versed in the Vedas and Vedanta. He is the great (acharya) of Sri Sampraday and is always devoted to the upliftment of the people. He got Shadakshar Mantra (रां रामाय नमः) from his Guru Raghavananadacharya Ji.

**(Agastya Samhitā Chapter 132, Shloka 13, 17)**

> रामानन्दः स्वयं रामः प्रादुर्भूतो महीतले ।
>
> कलौ लोके मुनिर्जातः सर्वजीव दयाकरः ॥

Śrīmad Rāmānandacharya is Śrī Rāma himself who appeared on this earth in the form of a great Muni (sage) out of his causeless mercy and compassion on all Jivas

**(-Nārad Panchrātra Vaishvānar Samhitā)**